# How to initialise a BigInteger array in the same way like an int[ ] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, biginteger

In the following code, I am unable to initialize the BigInteger array due to which a NullPointerException is thrown as I compile:

```
public class Solution {
public static BigInteger[] arr;
public Solution(int n){
    arr=new BigInteger[n];
    for(BigInteger each:arr){
        each=BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
}
public static BigInteger maxlist(){
    BigInteger max=arr[0];
    for(BigInteger elem:arr)
        if(elem.compareTo(max)>0)
            max=elem;
    return max;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    Solution s=new Solution(n);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < m; a0++){
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        BigInteger k = in.nextBigInteger();
        for(int i=a-1;i<=b-1;i++)
        arr[i]=arr[i].add(k);   //Error is thrown here
    }
    System.out.println(maxlist());
    in.close();
}
```

}

Error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Solution.main(Solution.java:29)`

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Are you providing any input here `BigInteger k = in.nextBigInteger();`? Probably `k` is getting the null value there.

Comment: Yes, actually an input is being provided which is not null.

Comment: This wouldn't work with an `int[]` either, but there the values default to `0` as it is an array of a primitive type.

Comment: Moderators..Can you please tell me where is the question asked before marking it duplicate?

Comment: @Vinay: You can see that at the top of the question you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your array initialization is incorrect.

```
for(Type obj : arr) {
   // in this context, obj does not refer to a part of the array.
   // obj is an iteration variable, assigning values to obj will not affect the array.
}
```

You need to assign to the array via the indices instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
}
```

Your full constructor should look something like this:

```
public Solution(int n){
    arr = new BigInteger[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean by using valueOf()?Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify. Look at your Constructor code, that's where your issue is :)

Comment: Ohh..But i am fond of Foreach Loop. Can it be done using foreach??

Comment: No, as I explained, foreach takes each reference from the array and places it in a temporary iteration variable once. Updating iteration variables does not have any effect.

Comment: Yeah. Now I get it..